# POST route annotation symfony2

Tags: symfony, routes

I am trying to develop a rest api, I have a problem with routes annotations, for gets it works well, my code for get is as follows

```
    /**
 * @QueryParam(name="offset", requirements="\d+", nullable=true, description="Offset from which to start listing pages.")
 * @QueryParam(name="limit", requirements="\d+", nullable=true, default="20", description="How many pages to return.")
 *
 * @View()
 *
 * @param Request               $request      the request object
 * @param ParamFetcherInterface $paramFetcher param fetcher service
 * GET Route annotation.
 * @Get("/users/")
 * @return array
 */
public function getUsersAction(Request $request, ParamFetcherInterface $paramFetcher)
{
    $offset = $paramFetcher->get('offset');
    $offset = null == $offset ? 0 : $offset;
    $limit = $paramFetcher->get('limit');

    return $this->container->get('user.handler')->all($limit, $offset);
}
```

for post I do not know how to do it, my code is as follows, i want to add attribues of user in the url, how to do that plz

```
         /**
* @View(template = "UserBundle:User:register.html.twig", statusCode = Codes::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST, templateVar = "form")
*
* @param Request $request the request object
* POST Route annotation.
* @Post("/users/")
* @return FormTypeInterface|View
*/
public function postUserAction(Request $request)
{
    try {
        $newUser = $this->get('user.handler')->post($request);

        $routeOptions = array(
                'id' => $newUser->getId(),
                '_format' => $request->get('_format')
        );

        return $this->routeRedirectView('get_user', $routeOptions, Codes::HTTP_CREATED);
    } catch (InvalidFormException $exception) {

        return $exception->getForm();
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems you forgot to mention that you are using the FOSRestBundle. Is that correct?

Comment: yes i use fosRestBundle

Answer (score 0):

You can get those parameters from the request:

```
/**
* @View(template = "UserBundle:User:register.html.twig", statusCode = Codes::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST, templateVar = "form")
*
* @param Request $request the request object
* POST Route annotation.
* @Route("/user/{name}/{email}")
* @Method("POST")
* @return FormTypeInterface|View
*/
public function postUserAction(Request $request, $name, $email)
{
    try {

        $newUser = $this->get('user.handler')->post($request);         

        $routeOptions = array(
                'id' => $newUser->getId(),
                '_format' => $request->get('_format')
        );

        return $this->routeRedirectView('get_user', $routeOptions, Codes::HTTP_CREATED);
    } catch (InvalidFormException $exception) {

        return $exception->getForm();
    }
}
```

Comment: how can i do that please ?

Comment: in my case, i want to add in urm attributes of a user to post it.. like  user/fabian/fabian@gmail.com/....

Comment: I've updated the answer, you can add routing placeholders. Read more in documentation http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#routing-with-placeholders. Alse, you can add requirements and defaults: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#adding-http-method-requirements

Comment: @AnnaAdamchuk Good one. Get and Post in FOSRestBundle extending the Route annotation, so I suppose, you can use placeholders in those also (eg: Post("/user/{name}/{email}")

Comment: Please, can you show your final code and exception text?

Comment: yes message":"An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO fos_user (username, username_canonical, email, email_canonical, enabled, salt, password, last_login, locked, expired, expires_at, confirmation_token, password_requested_at, roles, credentials_expired, credentials_expire_at, company_id, adress_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [null, \"\", null, \"\", 0, \"dmj6wi7jczcwc80wo88k8co4k8wc0so\", null, null, 0, 0, null, null, null, \"a:0:{}\", 0, null, null, null]:\n\nSQLSTATE[23000]